Is it safe to update wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt manually?
I see that wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt was last updated in 2020.
https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html has implemented numerous updates since then.
Can I overwrite WP's ca-bundle.crt?


Can I overwrite WP's ca-bundle.crt?

No.
This file and any other files in the wp-includes folder should never be updated modified or edited unless it's to replace them with a newer version of WordPress.
If you decide to ignore that and manually update the file anyway there are several consequences:

on managed hosts this won't work as WordPress core is handled separately and may not be on the same filesystem and read only. Likewise many enterprise hosts protect these folders through other means that are more structural.
the file would no longer match the file hash recorded for your version of WordPress, any security plugin would immediatley flag it
it would be overwritten on update, possibly even on every deploy
you would lose some WordPress specific backwards compatibility modifications:
## Includes a WordPress Modification - We include the 'legacy' 1024bit. 
certificates
## for backward compatibility. See 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34935#comment:10



Importantly though, your system might not be using that certificate bundle at all! This is in the original changeset that introduced it:

This changeset also bundles ca-bundle.crt from the Mozilla project to allow for us to verify SSL certificates on hosts which have an incomplete, outdated, or invalid local SSL configuration.

Instead of updating it on your host, you might consider instead contributing an update to WordPress itself aiming for the next major version ( 6.7 is in beta at the time of writing ). Here's the history https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commits/master/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt

The usual advice here is Don't Update Core Files, since any WordPress update may overwrite your changes and destroy something you've done.
wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt is used by the WP_Http class; any changes to the certificate file may impact how that class — and any class that builds upon it — functions.
Per the comments in the header of wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt:

## Certificate data from Mozilla as of: Wed Jul 22 03:12:14 2020 GMT
## Includes a WordPress Modification - We include the 'legacy' 1024bit certificates
## for backward compatibility. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34935#comment:10

The relevant ticket in Core Trac
It looks like WordPress has added these certificates back in after they were removed by Mozilla:

GTE CyberTrust Global Root
Thawte Server CA
Thawte Premium Server CA
Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2
ValiCert Class 1 VA
ValiCert Class 2 VA
ValiCert Class 3 VA (incorrectly called RSA Root Certificate 1)
Entrust.net Secure Server CA
Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA
Equifax Secure eBusiness CA 1
NetLock Business (Class B) Root
NetLock Express (Class C) Root
Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority

